# Imoprt product issues for product store wise

Tags: magento, csv, import

Hello I am try to import csv for my german store product name other some information. so i export one product for getting csv. i tried with with singal record i just set my information inplace of other but i get problem like that "Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined."

For that i am searching on net and do this kind of step describe on this links.

http://tutorialmagento.com/magento-skipping-import-row-required-field-sku-is-not-defined-how-to-fix

But its not worked any one have idea i attached here my csv formate

Getting my csv here [here](http://dev.starcufflinks.co.uk/export_product_test.csv)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your csv format comma separate or tab separated matches your configuration.This happens when Magento expects values separated by some other delimeter and you have separated using some other separator